# AngularJS what should be tested

Tags: php, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, e2e-testing

So me and my team are creating a web application and we are doing this:

- one of them is responsible for the API:

  - the api will serve the UI, will provide it with data and has the possibility to provide the fields the UI wants, sorted and everything, basically it filters all the data so the UI does not have to.
- Another one is responsible for the UI:

  - The UI will consume the API and present the data
- I am doing the test but i am doing the tests after the code. I test both the API (phpunit - unit tests and integration tests) and the UI (jasmine - unit tests and protractor - e2e tests)

So what should I really test?

Most of the controller functions on angularJS are fetching data and assign it to the $scope so are these functions worth to unit test?

Example of controller method:

```
UnidadesOrganicasService.getUnidadesOrganicas().then(function (unidadesOrganicas) {
                $scope.unidadesOrganicas = unidadesOrganicas;
            }, function errorCallback() {
                $scope.showToastError('Occorreu um erro a carregar as unidades orgânicas!');
            });
```

The other methods are making basically the same with some if's that depends on the data that comes from the API.

service method:

```
this.getUnidadesOrganicas = function () {
        return Restangular.all("unidades-organicas").getList({"sort": "acronimo"});
    };
```

So the test would be like this:

- mock the data with the $httpBackend
- check of the scope has the correct mocked data, but this would result in something like this: `expect($scope.something).toEqual(MockedSomething);` and the http mock would be just this: `$httpBackend.expectGET('/something').respond(MockedSomething);`

I know that E2E tests on the UI are very important but in this case are the unit tests worth to make for this kind of methods? Or should I just test the really important methods like calculus methods and methods like that?

On the other hand in the API most of the features seems irrelevant to make integration tests and unit tests seems much more important.

My real question is if I am thinking right and some orientation on what to test in this case.

**EDIT 1:**

Another question: In my case (I test after the code, not test-driven development), I should only test after the controller is complete (doing what it is supposed to do but can be refactored a little) right?

Comment: Sure, you may start with e2e/acceptance and then refactor the project for fine-grained tests when you will have time. If nobody from the team had solid experience with TDD app design, it would be too risky to begin refactoring in the middle of nowhere.

Comment: yeah we dont have much experience in testing :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always depends on project's budget and complexity. In the first place it is your own experience with the project that can tell you where you can get off cheap and where the lack of test coverage will cost money and make you tear your hair.

Credits to Angular for making controller unit testing real, bot most times I would skip it and leave it for e2e, this is especially true if you keep the controllers thin.

If you're really confident about your backend testing, you could potentially skip `$httpBackend` and get one step higher on the promise chain if service design allows this, that's undesirable but feasible scenario.

Comment: Thank you, I will consider that, the problem here is the deadline not the money, but also time is money xD I will not accept already because i want to see some more answers first. But thank you!

Comment: Yes, some instructive examples from the community would be to the point.